# ExoPlayer testing - Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: java, android, multithreading, exoplayer

I'm trying to test a class that I created that instantiates a new `SimpleExoPlayer` object, here's the class:

```
public class PlayerFactory {
    public static SimpleExoPlayer getPlayerInstance(Context context, Uri fileUri, String encryptionProtocol, byte[] secretKey, byte[] iv)
            throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        //Controls track changes
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();

        //Controls buffering
        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

        //Extracts data from data source
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

        //Factory of EncryptedFileDataSource
        DataSource.Factory encryptedFileDataSourceFactory = new EncryptedFileDataSourceFactory(encryptionProtocol, secretKey, iv, null);

        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(fileUri, encryptedFileDataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

        //Creates a SimpleExoPlayer instance
        SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector, loadControl);

        //Attache media source to player
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);

        return simpleExoPlayer;
    }
}
```

And then in `PlayerTest.java` class I try to test if the resulting object from `PlayerFactory.getPlayerInstance()` call is equal to `SimpleExoPlayer` class object.

Here's the test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class PlayerTest {
    //Encryption algorithm
    static final String ENC_ALG = "AES";
    //Encryption block mode
    static final String ENC_PROTOCOL = ENC_ALG + "/CTR/NoPadding";
    //File to be played
    static final String ENC_FILE = "song_encrypted_ctr.mp3";
    //Secrect key used in encryption
    public static final String mKey = "0123456789012345";
    //Initialization vector used in encryption
    public static final String mIV = "abcdefrtyqowueyr";

    @Test
    public void testCorrectIqraalyPlayerObject() throws Throwable {
        Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
        SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer = PlayerFactory.getPlayerInstance(context, Uri.parse("testuri"), ENC_PROTOCOL, mKey.getBytes(), mIV.getBytes());
        Assert.assertEquals(SimpleExoPlayer.class.getName(), simpleExoPlayer.getClass().getName());
    }
```

But I always get a `RuntimeException` :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that
>   has not called Looper.prepare()

on this line:

```
SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer = PlayerFactory.getPlayerInstance(context, Uri.parse("testuri"), ENC_PROTOCOL, mKey.getBytes(), mIV.getBytes());
```

I've noticed inside `ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance()` method in `PlayerFactory` there's a new Handler creation and passing around, I don't know what it's for. If anyone has an idea why is this happening I'd be grateful. Thanks.

---

**Update**:
I tried to use `@UiThreadTest` instead of `@Test` and I got this error:

> java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

---

**Update 2**: 
I tried to use both  `@UiThreadTest` and `@Test` I got:

> Given caller package com.example.rafael.exoplayerpoc.test is not
>   running in process ProcessRecord{c32179c
>   10198:com.example.rafael.exoplayerpoc/u0a58}

Answer (score 1):

Use `UiThreadTestRule` to run your test on UI thread. More details [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/UiThreadTestRule.html)

Comment: Please check the update. I got `No runnable methods`

Comment: you actually need both

Comment: Yea I got another error : `Given caller package com.example.rafae.exoplayerpoc.test is not running in process ProcessRecord{c32179c 10198:com.example.rafael.exoplayerpoc/u0a58}`